# set prefetch limit from stomp API

Tags: python, stomp, prefetch, amq

The AMQ [docs](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) note that the prefetch limit can be set when establishing a connection - is there a way to set the prefetch limit using ***stomp.py*** when instantiating a queue connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've asked myself this question as well, so if anyone still needs help with this issue:

It is possible to add ActiveMQ headers as dictionaries. The full list of possible configuration is [here](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html).

So for example to do what you needed to change prefetch limit, you need to add headers in subscribe:

```
connection = stomp.Connection()
connection.start()
connection.connect('username', 'password', wait=True)

# set callback
connection.set_listener('', self)
connection.subscribe(destination='/queue/test', id=1, ack='auto', headers={'activemq.prefetchSize': 1})
```

Comment: I used the same code and the header but it didn't work for me

Comment: You need to use ack="client" or "client-individual" 
because with ack=auto server does not wait for the clients ack and sends messages continuously assuming that the client can consume the message at any rate.